# Error when trying to add additional mailbox in Outlook: The name could not be resolved

Tags: exchange, outlook, microsoft-office

I am trying to open an additional mailbox in Outlook 2003 for one of my users. She already has three additional mailboxes in the list (found in the advanced account settings), and these work fine. When I click the "Add..." button, it immediately reports:

> The name could not be resolved. The
>   action could not be completed.

This is ***before*** I am prompted for the name.

We're using an externally hosted Exchange 2007 server.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Try disabling cached exchange mode on the client.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue for a remote user.  Driving me nuts because I could do it in the office, but not on his computer.  I found that by forcing Outlook to lookup his name (as though I was going to change the main mailbox) that I could then press Add and be prompted for a user name - which then was added as an additional mailbox.

Comment: Right-On Ken. I just had this identical scenario. I deleted a character from the primary user's name, re-added it, clicked on Check Name, verified by underline, then clicked More Settings to finish adding the additional mailbox. So simple, yet so frustrating. thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

On the PC try ipconfig /flushdns.

If you have a local DNS server try clearing the cache, if you are using an external server for DNS try switching to an alternate server, eg Open DNS. See if that fixes the problem.

Otherwise can you recreate the issue on another machine? - setup the same mailbox plus the additional mailboxes, see if you get the same error.

If so it sounds like the problem could be on the Exchange Server side. You should speak to the Exchange hosting provider and see if they can resolve the problem.

Microsoft has a [KB](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;Q322832) article about the error message, but its for Exchange 2003.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work with the same user on another computer? It could be good to rule out (or confirm) a client issue. You can also try creating a new Outlook profile, if you don't have another client available for testing.

Answer (score 0):

I get this if the mailbox is hidden from the global address book. In such a case I unhide it, add the mailbox and hide it again.